# Manipulating data in a complex mongoDB data model

Tags: mongodb

```
{
name: “Bimal”,
role: “developer”,
reports_to: “girish”,
technology:[{
  name: “PHP”,
  rating: 5
},{
  name: “JavaScript”,
  rating: 4    
}],
project: [{
    project_name: “TGT”,
    client_name: “Said”,
    estimated_time: 20,
    tasks: [{
        start_time: new Date(2013, 2, 13, 7, 47),
        end_time: new Date(2013, 2, 15, 7, 47),
        Description: “design the page”
    }, {
        start_time: new Date(2013, 3, 13, 7, 47),
        end_time: new Date(2013, 2, 13, 7, 47),
        Description: “coding the page”
    }]
}]
```

}

I have this complex database structure. Now I need to add a new technology and a rating to it after JavaScript.Also I need to edit the description of the task which has a a description  "design the page".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new Technology use either $push or $addToSet. To update the description in the Project section use the positional operator $ with $set . Remember in subdocument order is not maintain all the time . So In case you want the order in the technology key , please add one more key called Order and use it in each subdocument . While showing on the client side you can order it . 
I removed my second query . One of the way if you wish to do even with limitation is that you can pull the data in the client side and then update the document and save it back , but there is no direct command to do so , you have to loop in client side

```
db.Collection.update({"name" : "Bimal"} , { "technology" : { $addToSet : { name: “New Technology”,rating: 1}}})
```

If possible and if you are OK , you can re structure you document like this

```
  {tasks : [{ "ProjectName: "" , startDate : "" , EndDate : "" , Description : "" } ]
```

I know it will duplicate the data many times but this will one of the way that you can update any fields in the tasks sub document.

Comment: getting "can't append to array using string field name: tasks" error for updating tasks

Comment: My bad , i did not saw Project will contain the sub document it self . I am afraid to say that YOU can NOT do it https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongodb-user/_4C1oD3aaCU . There is even open JIRA ticket https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831

Comment: I updated my reply with couple of more solution , just have a look